# How can retrieve data from various entries (each single-line), calculate it, then be able to display results in real time?

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I would like to know a way to able to retrieve data from various entries from a Grid Layout and have their values ready to calculate inside other classes/methods. I want the results to automatically change depending on what you enter in the Score, ScoreGot and Weight of each grade.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="GradeThisForMe.GradeCalculator"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             BackgroundImage="WallpaperBlueSkyBlurMedium.png">
    <StackLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <Grid x:Name="tableGrid" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Text="Target Grade: " Style="{StaticResource GridTopLabelStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  />
        <Entry Text="{Binding TargetGrade}" Style="{StaticResource GridTopEntryStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"/>

        <Label Text="Current Grade: " Style="{StaticResource GridTopLabelStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  />
        <Label Text="{Binding AverageGrade}" Style="{StaticResource GridTopLabelStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

        <Label Text="You need: " Style="{StaticResource GridTopLabelStyle}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  />
        <Label Text="{Binding GradeNeeded}" Style="{StaticResource GridTopLabelStyle}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

        <Label Text="#" Style="{StaticResource GridBottomLabelStyle}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Label Text="Score" Style="{StaticResource GridBottomLabelStyle}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Text="Score Got" Style="{StaticResource GridBottomLabelStyle}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Label Text="Weight" Style="{StaticResource GridBottomLabelStyle}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3"/>

        <Entry Text="{Binding Grade1Name}" Style="{StaticResource GridBottomEntryStyle}" Placeholder="Grade#1" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Entry Text="{Binding Score1}" Style="{StaticResource GridNumericEntryStyle}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Entry Text="{Binding ScoreGot1}" Style="{StaticResource GridNumericEntryStyle}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Entry Text="{Binding Weight1}" Style="{StaticResource GridNumericEntryStyle}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3"/>

        <Entry  Style="{StaticResource GridBottomEntryStyle}" Placeholder="Grade#2" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Entry  Style="{StaticResource GridNumericEntryStyle}"  Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Entry  Style="{StaticResource GridNumericEntryStyle}"  Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Entry  Style="{StaticResource GridNumericEntryStyle}"  Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3"/>

        <Entry Style="{StaticResource GridBottomEntryStyle}" Placeholder="Grade#3" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Entry Style="{StaticResource GridNumericEntryStyle}" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Entry Style="{StaticResource GridNumericEntryStyle}" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Entry Style="{StaticResource GridNumericEntryStyle}" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="3"/>

        <Entry Style="{StaticResource GridBottomEntryStyle}" Placeholder="Grade#4" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Entry Style="{StaticResource GridNumericEntryStyle}" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Entry Style="{StaticResource GridNumericEntryStyle}" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Entry Style="{StaticResource GridNumericEntryStyle}" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="3"/>

        <Entry Style="{StaticResource GridBottomEntryStyle}" Placeholder="Grade#5" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Entry Style="{StaticResource GridNumericEntryStyle}" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Entry Style="{StaticResource GridNumericEntryStyle}" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Entry Style="{StaticResource GridNumericEntryStyle}" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="3"/>

        <Entry Style="{StaticResource GridBottomEntryStyle}" Placeholder="Grade#6" Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Entry Style="{StaticResource GridNumericEntryStyle}" Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Entry Style="{StaticResource GridNumericEntryStyle}" Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Entry Style="{StaticResource GridNumericEntryStyle}" Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="3"/>

            </Grid>

        </ScrollView>
        <Button Text="Calculate"
        Style="{StaticResource PrimaryButton}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

For testing purposes, my goal is to change and display the results of AverageGrade in real time after entering the score and score got in grade#1. To notice property changes, the value has to be a string. To calculate results, In Grade1Total, I tried to convert the Score1 and ScoreGot1 values temporarily into double. After converting the calculation results to string, it never shows up on display. What do you recommend I should do?

***Note:*** I know that some parts of the code like Calculate button are incomplete or unnecessary. My priority right now is to fix this situation.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace GradeThisForMe
{
    public class AddGradesDetails: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string targetGrade;

        string grade1_Name;

        string score1;
        double dbl_score1;

        string score_got1;
        double dbl_score_got1;

        string weight1;

        string total_grade1;
        double dbl_total_grade1;

        string decimal_weight1;
        string average_grade;

        string grade_needed;



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string total_grade1 = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(total_grade1));
        }

        public string Grade1Name
        {
            get { return grade1_Name; }
            set
            {
                grade1_Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(Grade1Name);


            }


        }

        public string Score1
        {
            get { return score1; }
            set
            {

                score1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(Score1);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AverageGrade));

            }




        }

        public string ScoreGot1
        {
            get { return score_got1; }
            set
            {
                score_got1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(ScoreGot1);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AverageGrade));



            }



    } 

        public string Weight1
        {
            get { return weight1; }
            set
            {
                weight1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(Weight1);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AverageGrade));

            }



        }

        public string Grade1Total
        {
            get { return total_grade1; }
            set
            {


                dbl_score1 = Convert.ToDouble(Score1);
                dbl_score_got1 = Convert.ToDouble(ScoreGot1);
                dbl_total_grade1 = ((dbl_score_got1 / dbl_score1)*100);

                total_grade1 = Convert.ToString(dbl_score1);
                OnPropertyChanged(Grade1Total);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AverageGrade));

            }


        }


        public string AverageGrade
        {
            get { return $"{Grade1Total}"; }
            set
            {


                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AverageGrade));
            }



        }
        public string TargetGrade
        {
            get { return targetGrade; }
            set
            {
                targetGrade = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(TargetGrade);
            }


        }

        public string GradeNeeded
        {
            get { return grade_needed; }
            set
            {

            }
        }


    }




}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I’m still in progress making the app. After I read the documents, I realized that I didn’t need to convert any values. I also learned a lot of other things. Thanks for the resource.

Comment: Does your problem resolved?

Comment: For now, yes. The app works using double type objects. The only thing that might be bothersome for  some is that by using the get set objects as double type, the entries appear with a “0” on it. If someone wants something more custom like setting if condition if the entry is blank then your example, Jack Hua could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Just update the value of in the binding model. Set the `detailsModel` as `BindingContext` and update the value of `detailsModel.Result` when you click Calculate button. Here is a simple example:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    AddGradesDetails detailsModel;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        detailsModel = new AddGradesDetails();
        detailsModel.Score1 = "1";
        detailsModel.ScoreGot1 = "2";
        detailsModel.Result = "";

        BindingContext = detailsModel;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double result = Convert.ToDouble(detailsModel.Score1) + Convert.ToDouble(detailsModel.ScoreGot1);

        detailsModel.Result = result.ToString();
    }
}
```

And in xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <Grid x:Name="tableGrid" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Text="Target Grade: " Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  />
            <Entry Text="{Binding TargetGrade}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"/>

            <Label Text="Current Grade: " Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  />
            <Label Text="{Binding AverageGrade}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

            <Label Text="You need: " Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  />
            <Label Text="{Binding GradeNeeded}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

            <Label Text="#" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Label Text="Score" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Label Text="Score Got" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <Label Text="Weight" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3"/>

            <Entry Text="{Binding Grade1Name}" Placeholder="Grade#1" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding Score1}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding ScoreGot1}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding Result}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3"/>

        </Grid>

    </ScrollView>
    <Button Text="Calculate" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
</StackLayout>
```

The model:

```
public class AddGradesDetails : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string grade1_Name { get; set; }
    string score1 { get; set; }
    string score_got1 { get; set; }
    string result { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public string Grade1Name
    {
        get { return grade1_Name; }
        set
        {
            grade1_Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Grade1Name");
        }
    }

    public string Score1
    {
        get { return score1; }
        set
        {
            if (value != score1)
            {
                score1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Score1");
            }               
        }
    }

    public string ScoreGot1
    {
        get { return score_got1; }
        set
        {
            score_got1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ScoreGot1");
        }
    }

    public string Result
    {
        get { return result; }
        set
        {
            result = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Result");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was busy doing school work.  Right now, the app works by changing the get set objects in double types. The only catch is the entries appear with a zero when loading the app. For some, this might be an inconvience if you plan on using an if condition to check if the entry is blank. If someone desire to do so then you’re example could be useful.

After classes ends, I will try out this method. But for now, I’ll stick using double type since I don’t have much time left.

Comment: By the way, thanks for the response. I appreaciate your help.

Comment: No problem, happy coding:).